# Advatanges and disadvantages of using theme extensions for storing colors instead of class

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

What are the advantages of using theme extension for storing custom colors instead of class containing static consts?

```
class AppColors {    
   static const Color brandColor = Color(0xFF1E88E5);
   static const Color danger = Color(0xFFE53935);
   //...
}
```

vs

```
@immutable
class MyColors extends ThemeExtension<MyColors> {
  const MyColors({
    required this.brandColor,
    required this.danger,
  });
  //...
}

//...
final MyColors myColors = Theme.of(context).extension<MyColors>()!;
```

One advantages for class is that it does not require context. What are the prons of theme extensions?

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but I guess if you want to automatically toggle between night and day color schemes, you need themes - or at least it makes toggling a lot easier

Comment: Either way you have to use colors from the class or from the extension to initiate light and dark schema so if I am not mistaken it's the same process for both

Answer (score 0):

Using a class alone like you are showing won't allow you your code to automatically change between different themes or settings in your app.

For example

```
class AppColors {    
   static const Color brandColor = Color(0xFF1E88E5);
   static const Color danger = Color(0xFFE53935);
   //...
}

class AppDarkColors {    
   static const Color brandColor = Color(0xFF1E88E5); //imagine some other color, other than appColor
   static const Color danger = Color(0xFFE53935);
   //...
}
```

Usage

Not only would you need to manage the brightness manually somehow, but also conditionally change color in your widget.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
   Brightness brightness;
   MyWidget({super.key, this.brightness = Brightness.light });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Color myColor; 
   if(brightness == Brightness.light){
     myColor = AppColors.brandColor;
   } else {
      myColor = AppDarkColors.brandColor;
   }
   return const Placeholder();
   }
 }
```

And sure, you could pass in parameters to your class to simplify the conditional there, but will still need to add the logic of getting the brightness which could be by system, or forced to light o dark manually.

However, using **ThemeExtensions** solves this by auto managing the themes in your materiaApp, you define your extensions for each theme you have and for light and dark, and anywhere in your code the usage is the same no  extra code or checks.

```
<pre>
<code>
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Brightness brightness;
   MyWidget({super.key, this.brightness = Brightness.light });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color myColor = Theme.of(context).extension<MyAppColors>().brandColor;
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
</code>
</pre>
```

To set up prepare your extension

```
<pre>
<code>
@immutable
class MyAppColors extends ThemeExtension<MyAppColors> {
  
  const MyAppColors({
    required this.brandColor,
    required this.danger,
  });

  final Color? brandColor;
  final Color? danger;

  @override
  ThemeExtension<MyAppColors> copyWith({Color? brandColor, Color? danger}) {
    return MyAppColors(
      brandColor: brandColor ?? this.brandColor,
      danger: danger ?? this.danger,
    );
  }

  @override
  ThemeExtension<MyAppColors> lerp(ThemeExtension<MyAppColors>? other, double t) {
    if (other is! MyAppColors) {
      return this;
    }
    return MyAppColors(
      brandColor: Color.lerp(brandColor, other.brandColor, t),
      danger: Color.lerp(danger, other.danger, t),
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'MyAppColors(brandColor: $brandColor, danger: $danger)';
  }

  static const light = MyAppColors(
    brandColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
    danger: Colors.red,
  );

  static const dark = MyAppColors(
    brandColor: Colors.pink,
    danger: Colors.redAccent,
  );
}
</code>
</pre>
```

and add to your material app

```
<pre>
<code>
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'my App',
      theme:ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        extensions: [
          MyAppColors.dark
        ]
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        extensions: [
          MyAppColors.light
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
</code>
</pre>
```

Notice that extensions allow you to set up themes and can be changed to other themes or in different parts of your application. But the key part is that your widgets usage remains unchanged since everything you get is from your theme context.

To know more check out how themes work in flutter.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html